# Extracting ints within a String with digits and letters

Tags: java

```
protected void intFinder(int k, String inputLine) {
        int legnth = inputLine.length();
        Integer extractedNumber = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < legnth; i++) {
            Character character = inputLine.charAt(i);
            if (character.equals(":")) {
                i++;
                extractedNumber += character;
                character = inputLine.charAt(i);
            } else if (character.equals(",")) {
                i++;
                character = inputLine.charAt(i);
                while (Character.isDigit(character)) {
                    extractedNumber += character;
                    i++;
                    character = inputLine.charAt(i);
                }

            //code ommited
```

I’m trying to 3 ints out of a String that is a mix of letters and digits for example avfds:10,5,14 but if character.equals(":") is never showing as true and im not sure why. Thanks for any help

int k is used later in a switch shouldn’t be relevant at this point

Comment: `equals()` is usually "type aware" so `String` is never equals to `Character`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using chars, try using a simple quote (') instead of double (")

Comment: Cheers that worked the double quotes are type specific and the single are not in java does that mean?

Comment: Double quotes are used for strings and simple ones for characters, simple as that. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String s : "avfds:10,5,14".split(":")[1].split(","))
    System.out.println(s);
```

output:

```
10
5
14
```

or:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList("avfds:10,5,14".split(":")[1].split(",")));
```

output:

```
[10, 5, 14]
```

Comment: This way works and is quicker for most situations just doing int i = Integer.parseInt(s); would give you ints for each.  (im doing it differently for a reason) I would upvote but i dont have the rep

Answer (score 0):

With some [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries):

```
package com.stackoverflow.so20477116;

import com.google.common.base.CharMatcher;
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;

import java.util.List;

public class Extract {

    private static final Splitter SPLITTER = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.JAVA_DIGIT.negate()).omitEmptyStrings();

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final List<Integer> result = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.transform(SPLITTER.split("avfds:10,5,14"), ToInt.INSTANCE));
        System.out.println(result); // [10, 5, 14]
    }

    // String => Integer
    private static enum ToInt implements Function<String, Integer> {
        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public Integer apply(final String input)
        {
            return input == null ? null : Ints.tryParse(input);
        }
    }
}
```

**References:**

- [Guava's string utilities, explained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained)
- [`Splitter` javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)
- [`CharMatcher` javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html)